# Rcpp get element by name - $ operator

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

In `R` I can write:

```
l <- list(a=0, b="10");
```

And get the value of the element of the list named `b` as follow:

```
x <– l$b
```

Is there a way to get the same result by using an `Rcpp::List` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, and there are plenty of examples. Just use

```
std::string x = l["b"];
```

where `l` is the `Rcpp::List` object which is assumed to have names.